# How are request counted in Google Location API (Android)

Tags: android, google-maps, geolocation

Sorry if this question is obvious, I haven´t found a clear answer in other posts.

I am creating an Android app and I am planning to use the Google API to get a more accurate location. My question is about the request limit of the API(2500 request per day if you don´t pay): I guess that every time I call [getLastLocation()](https://developer.android.com/training/location/retrieve-current.html) counts as a request, but in my app I want to update the location periodically using [LocationRequest](https://developer.android.com/training/location/change-location-settings.html) methods like setInterval()

Thank you in advance.

Comment: from where you read about this limit?

Comment: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geolocation/usage-limits?hl=en-419 . Does´t it applies for what I am speaking about?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

taking geo-location and plotting it on Map are two different things.

To get geo-location there in no such limit as of now! From Android version O, there will be such limit for background location limit refer this [URL](https://developer.android.com/preview/features/background-location-limits.html)

to Plot the coordinates on map these is such limit as mentioned [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geolocation/usage-limits?hl=en-419)

so your can take any amount of location data,but plotting it on Map is limited i.e 2500/day.

Comment: Ok thanks! Very useful answer, I thought the location request were included in those limits.